# An error in my while loop that does not always show

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic, procedural-generation, procedural-programming

I am trying to make a random map generator.

The map is 24x24.

The error does not always show. When it does show it is in the "Do/While" loop at the end of the function.

Specifically in the "while" line.

```
function randKeyRoomsLoc(tempMap, dir, locked, room, displayRooms, before){
  var location = [];//creates array to store rooms location
  if (dir == "n" || dir == "w") {//if directions is NORTH or west
    if (before) {
      before = false;//if before is true turn to false
    }else {
      before = true;// if before is false turn to true
    }
  }
  if (dir == "w" || dir == "e") {// if directions is W or E
    var lockedRoom = locked[1];
  }else {
    var lockedRoom = locked[0];
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < room.length; i++) {//loops thru the rooms
    if (before) {//are the rooms being place before locked?
      var tempX = lockedRoom + 2;//limist the 2 spaces from the LR
      x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(22 - tempX+1)+tempX);//limits the spawn 
      y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 24));
    }else {//are the rooms being place after locked?
      var tempX = lockedRoom - 2;//limist the 2 spaces from the LR
      x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(tempX - 0 + 1) + 0);//limits 
      y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 24));
    }
    if (dir == "w" || dir == "e") {//needs to exchange X & Y if W or E
      var tempX = y;
      var tempY = x;
      y = tempY;
      x = tempX
    }
    if (tempMap[x][y] == "#") {//checks to see the room is empty
      tempMap[x][y] = jQuery.extend(true, {}, room[i]);
      displayMap[x][y] = displayRooms[i];
    }else {//if its not empty
      if(dir == "w" || dir == "e"){// IF W OR E--------------------
        do {//excecute this once
          if (x < 21) {//if Y is less than the end
            x++;// we move Y one to the right
            if (y < lockedRoom) {//if X is less than the X of locked room
              y++;//moves X up
            }else {//if X is = or more than the X of lock
              y--;//moves it down
            }
          }else {//if Y is close to the end
            x--;//we move it back 5 places
            if (y < lockedRoom) {//if X is less than the X of locked room
              y++;//moves X up
            }else {//if X is = or more than the X of lock
              y--;//moves it down
            }
          }
        } while (tempMap[x][y] != "#");//check if room is empty,not loops
        tempMap[x][y] = jQuery.extend(true, {}, room[i]);
        displayMap[x][y] = displayRooms[i];
      }else {// IF S OR N---------------------------------------
        do {//excecute this once
          if (y < 21) {//if Y is less than the end
            y++;// we move Y one to the right
            if (x < lockedRoom) {//if X is less than the X of locked room
              x--;//moves X up
            }else {//if X is = or more than the X of lock
              x++;//moves it down
            }
          }else {//if Y is close to the end
            y--;//we move it back 5 places
            if (x < lockedRoom) {//if X is less than the X of locked room
              x--;//moves X up
            }else {//if X is = or more than the X of lock
              x++;//moves it down
            }
          }
        } while (tempMap[x][y] != "#");//check if room is empty,not loops
        tempMap[x][y] = jQuery.extend(true, {}, room[i]);
        displayMap[x][y] = displayRooms[i];
      }
    }
    location.push([x,y]);//saves the location of the room
  }
  return location;//returns the locations of all the rooms
}
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: And what is the error that you get?

Comment: Whats the error? How do you see there is an error? What is it supposed to do, that it doesn't do at the moment? What is it supposed not to do, that it still does?

Comment: Also before=!before and you only need one `tempMap[x][y] = jQuery.extend(true, {}, room[i]);`

Comment: please declare all variables in advance.

Comment: What is the error? What are you trying to ask? What is your question?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '21' of undefined....." The error is not always present, and the number changes.

Comment: Just log x and y